# Unable to run a conda command with subprocess.run enventhough conda init has been run

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, conda

As this snippet shows: `conda init` has been run, yet conda commands called with `subprocess.run()` disagree. Why?

```
In [9]: import subprocess                                                                                                     

In [10]: subprocess.run("conda activate test", shell=True)                                                                    

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.


Out[10]: CompletedProcess(args='conda activate test', returncode=1)

In [11]: !echo $SHELL                                                                                                         
/usr/bin/zsh

In [12]: !conda init zsh                                                                                                      
no change     /home/miniconda3/condabin/conda
no change     /home/miniconda3/bin/conda
no change     /home/miniconda3/bin/conda-env
no change     /home/miniconda3/bin/activate
no change     /home/miniconda3/bin/deactivate
etc.

No action taken.
```

**EDIT**:
the prefix solution given by cel does not seem to work here:

```
In [2]: subprocess.run("$CONDA_PREFIX/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && conda activate test", shell=True)                             

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.


Out[2]: CompletedProcess(args='$CONDA_PREFIX/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && conda activate test', returncode=1)
```

Comment: Generally, if you are planning to run conda from the notebook, consider using the `%conda` line magic - that is going make everything easier. If you really want to make the subprocess call work, you have to source conda.sh first: subprocess.run("/home/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && conda activate test", shell=True)

Comment: @cel Thank you; I am only coding in an ipython shell for debugging purposes: my goal is to run this command inside a python script.
1) When trying, I don't have permission to run the 1st conda.sh command 
2) If I have multiple conda commands in various locations in the code (like 10), is there a way to avoid prefixing them all with your suggestion ?

Comment: Regarding 1), I solved it with a preliminary `chmod +x $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/profile.d/conda.sh`

Answer (score 2):

In the end, the solution was (after making `$CONDA_PREFIX/etc/profile.d/conda.sh` executable with `chmod +x $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/profile.d/conda.sh`, and I had to use `.` instead of `source`):

```
subprocess.run(". $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && conda activate test", shell=True)
```

The issue is discussed at length here:
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7980

Comment: @cel Right, old habit of passing options with minus. Fixed, thanks!